# GROK pattern for optional field

Tags: logstash-grok

I have a log string like :

```
2018-08-02 12:02:25.904 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleTypeMismatch - Failed to bind request element
```

In the above string `[http-nio-8080-exec-1]` is a optional field, it can be there in some log statements.

i created a grok patterns like with some references on net :

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])? %{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:class}\.%{DATA:method} - %{GREEDYDATA:loggedString}
```

seems its not working if i remove the thread name string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to make the space character following the thread name optional: `(\[%{DATA:thread}\] )?`

input:

```
2018-08-02 12:02:25.904 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleTypeMismatch - Failed to bind request element
```

pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (\[%{DATA:thread}\] )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:class}\.%{DATA:method} - %{GREEDYDATA:loggedString}
```

output:

```
{
  "loggedString": "Failed to bind request element",
  "method": "handleTypeMismatch",
  "level": "WARN",
  "class": "o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver",
  "timestamp": "2018-08-02 12:02:25.904"
}
```

Comment: Its correct but how it worked ? i had given the space anyway right ?

Comment: you could compare the two patterns char by char and would find the difference.

Comment: I only different is i have give space outside `)?` and you have given inside. Not sure how its making a difference.

Comment: if the field is missing, the field separator - space char - should not be matched as well.